# Como hacer un archivo .json vacio que se llene con variables inputs y otros (usando angularjs)

Tags: html, angularjs

Mi problema es el siguiente: intento implementar una prueba online con angular js, quiero usar un archivo .json para almacenar las variables pero el problema es que, quiero que el .json este vacio y que se vaya llenando con los inputs de la página, es eso posible?.

Basicamente este es mi archivo .json:

```
{
    "datos":[
{
    "nombre":"",
    "apellido":"",
    "sede":"",
    "ci":""
}
    ],
}
```

Estas son las variables que quiero mostrar del código:

```
<div ng-show="tab == 6">
<!--Resultados obtenidos-->

<h1>Resultados obtenidos </h1><br><br>

<strong>La nota para el usuario: <br>


{{nombre+" "+apellido}}<br>
C.I.{{ci}}<br>
Sede:.{{sede}}<br>
<br><br>
Es:
<br><br>
{{count}}/20 </strong><br><br>

<b>Sobre 100 es:<br><br>
{{(count*100)/20}}/100<br></b><br><br>


<b>Ha tenido {{counterror/10}} errores</b><br><br>
<b style="color:#467FE2">**Los errores se contaran solo si se ha seleccionado la respuesta incorrecta, si no se ha seleccionado ninguna respuesta, el error no se contará**</b><br>
<br><br><br>

<center>
```

Y este es el codigo .js que corresponde al controlador del .json

```
 misDatos.controller('controladorDatos',function($scope,$http){
            $scope.importar = function(){
                $http.get('datos.json').sucess(function(datos){

                    $scope.informacion = datos;
                });

            }

$scope.importar();

});
```

Y finalmente este es mi código html completo:

```
<html ng-app="miAplicacion">
<head>
      <title>Proyecto prueba de lapso</title>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script> <!--Declarando Angular-->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!--Declarando Bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!--Declarando estilo css-->

<script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {


        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'x');
        data.addColumn('number', 'y');
        data.addRows([
          ['Correctas', 20],
          ['Fallidas', 10]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Resultados',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>

<br><br><br>
<img ng src="img/logo.jpg" with="200px" height="200px"><br><br>
<b>Escuela: </b>Computación<br>
<b>Materia: </b>Programación I<br>
<b>Semestre:</b> 2<br>
<b>Fecha: </b> <div ng-controller="fechaController">
   <span id ="fecha">{{CurrentDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</span>
</div>
Tiempo transcurrido: <span id="minutos">0</span>:<span id="segundos">0</span>
      </p>

<br><br>
</head>
<body>
<center><br><br>
<div ng-hide="tab == 6"><div ng-hide="tab == 5"><div ng-hide="tab == 4"><div ng-hide="tab == 3"><div  ng-hide="tab == 2"><div ng-hide="tab == 1"><input type="button" ng-click="tab = 0" value="Comenzar" ng-hide="tab == 0"><br></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<!--Parte0, Datos generales-->
<div ng-show="tab == 0">
<center><h2 style="color:#467FE2">Datos Generales</h2></center>

<b style="color:#FF0000">*Campos obligatorios</b><br><br>

<form name="agregarUsuarioForm">


<b>Nombre <b style="color:#FF0000">*</b></b></h5> <input ng-model="nombre" required><br><br>
<b>Apellido <b style="color:#FF0000">*</b></b></h5> <input ng-model="apellido" required><br><br>
<b>Sede: </b><br>
<input type="radio" name="sede" ng-model="sede" value="Los Naranjos">Los Naranjos
<input type="radio" name="sede" ng-model="sede" value="Centro">Centro<br><br>
<b>Cédula de identidad <b style="color:#FF0000">*</b></b></h5> <input ng-model="ci" required><br><br>
<br><br>
<button ng-show="agregarUsuarioForm.$valid" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" ng-click="tab = 1" ng-click="inicio();" onclick="carga()">Siguiente</button>
<br><br><br><br>
</form>

</div>



<!--Parte1-->
<div ng-show="tab == 1">
<center><h2 style="color:#467FE2"> Prueba en Línea </h2></center><br><br>

<h3>Parte 1</h3><br><br>

1.- Los ________________ son una secuencia de pasos lógicos para la solución de un
problema escrita en lenguaje natural.Valor: 2 puntos<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="respuesta" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2" ng-init="count=0">Algoritmos
<input type="radio" name="respuesta" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10" ng-init="counterror=0">Metodos cientificos
<input type="radio" name="respuesta" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10" ng-init="counterror=0">Teoremas de busquedas y respuestas
<input type="radio" name="respuesta" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10" ng-init="counterror=0">Ninguna de las anteriores

<br><br><br>
2.- Los ________ Son difíciles de aprender y manejar ya que no resultan cercanos al ser
humano.Valor: 2 puntos<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="respuesta2" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2">Lenguajes de bajo nivel
<input type="radio" name="respuesta2" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Lenguajes de alto nivel
<input type="radio" name="respuesta2" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Lenguajes de medio nivel
<input type="radio" name="respuesta2" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Ninguna de las anteriores

<br><br><br>

<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Regresar" ng-click="tab = 0">
<input type="button" value="Siguiente" ng-click="tab = 2">
<br><br><br><br>
</div>


<!--Parte2-->
<div ng-show="tab == 2">
<h3>Parte 2</h3><br><br>
3.- El lenguaje de ___________, es el que utiliza el ordenador.
Valor: 2 puntos<br><br>

<input type="radio" name="respuesta3" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2">Lenguaje de bajo nivel
<input type="radio" name="respuesta3" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Lenguaje de alto nivel
<input type="radio" name="respuesta3" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Lenguaje de medio nivel
<input type="radio" name="respuesta3" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Ninguna de las anteriores
<br><br><br><br>

4.- Los _______________ son utilizados para procesar y entender ____________ de un lenguaje.
Valor: 2 puntos<br><br>

<input type="radio" name="respuesta4" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Lectores USB, la estructura
<input type="radio" name="respuesta4" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Lectores de CD, el rendimiento
<input type="radio" name="respuesta4" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2">Compiladores, la codificación
<input type="radio" name="respuesta4" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Ninguna de las anteriores
<br><br><br><br>

<input type="button" value="Regresar" ng-click="tab = 1"></a>
<input type="button" value="Siguiente" ng-click="tab = 3" ng-hide="tab == 7"></a>
<br><br><br><br>
</div>


<!--Parte3-->
<div ng-show="tab == 3">
<h3>Parte 3</h3><br><br>
5.- El lenguaje natural es el lenguaje hablado o escrito por humanos para propósitos
generales de comunicación.<br><br>

<input type="radio" name="respuesta5" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2">Verdadero
<input type="radio" name="respuesta5" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Falso

<br><br>
6.- Un algoritmo debe ser: preciso, definido e infinito. Valor: 2 puntos.<br><br>

<input type="radio" name="respuesta6" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Verdadero
<input type="radio" name="respuesta6" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2">Falso

<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Regresar" ng-click="tab = 2">
<input type="button" value="Siguiente" ng-click="tab = 4">
<br><br><br><br>
</div>

<!--Parte4-->
<div ng-show="tab == 4">
<h3>Parte 4</h3><br><br>
7.- Los algoritmos cuantitativos se refieren a algoritmos que resuelven problemas cuyo
resultado es numérico.Valor: 2 puntos<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="respuesta7" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2" >Verdadero
<input type="radio" name="respuesta7" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Falso
<br><br>
8.- Un lenguaje de alto nivel son difíciles de aprender y permiten despreocuparse de la
arquitectura del ordenador.Valor: 2 puntos<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="respuesta8" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">Verdadero
<input type="radio" name="respuesta8" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2">Falso
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Regresar" ng-click="tab = 3">
<input type="button" value="Siguiente" ng-click="tab = 5">
<br><br><br><br>
</div>


<!--Parte5-->
<div ng-show="tab == 5">
<h3>Parte 5</h3><br><br>
9.- Un algoritmo debe ser: Valor: 2 puntos<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="respuesta9" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">a) Preciso, definido e infinito
<input type="radio" name="respuesta9" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2">b) Preciso, definido y finito
<input type="radio" name="respuesta9" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">c) Impreciso, definido e infinito
<input type="radio" name="respuesta9" value="correcta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10">d) Impreciso, definido y finito

<br><br>
10.- Los tipos de algoritmos son: Valor: 2 puntos<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="respuesta10" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10"> a) De calidad y cualitativos
<input type="radio" name="respuesta10" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10"> b) De cantidad y cuantitativos
<input type="radio" name="respuesta10" value="correcta" ng-click="count = count + 2"> c) Cualitativos y cuantitativos
<input type="radio" name="respuesta10" value="incorrecta" ng-click="counterror = counterror + 10"> d) De cantidad y cualitativos

<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Regresar" ng-click="tab = 4">
<div onclick="detenerse()"><input type="button" value="Enviar" ng-click="tab = 6" onclick="mostrar()" ></div>
<br><br><br><br>
</div>


<div ng-show="tab == 6">
<!--Resultados obtenidos-->

<h1>Resultados obtenidos </h1><br><br>

<strong>La nota para el usuario: <br>


{{nombre+" "+apellido}}<br>
C.I.{{ci}}<br>
Sede:.{{sede}}<br>
<br><br>
Es:
<br><br>
{{count}}/20 </strong><br><br>

<b>Sobre 100 es:<br><br>
{{(count*100)/20}}/100<br></b><br><br>


<b>Ha tenido {{counterror/10}} errores</b><br><br>
<b style="color:#467FE2">**Los errores se contaran solo si se ha seleccionado la respuesta incorrecta, si no se ha seleccionado ninguna respuesta, el error no se contará**</b><br>
<br><br><br>

<center>



<div ng-show="count == 20"><b>Matrícula de Honor.</b>
Felicitaciones, su puntuación a sido la mejor. Ha pasado la prueba satisfactoriamente sin ningun error.
<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 19"><b>Sobresaliente</b>
Felicitaciones, su puntuación a sido la sobresaliente. Ha pasado la prueba satisfactoriamente, con pocos errores.
<br><br>
</div>


<div ng-show="count == 18"><b>Sobresaliente</b>
Felicitaciones, su puntuación a sido la sobresaliente. Ha pasado la prueba satisfactoriamente, con pocos errores.
<br><br>
</div>


<div ng-show="count == 17"><b>Sobresaliente</b>
Felicitaciones, su puntuación a sido la sobresaliente. Ha pasado la prueba satisfactoriamente, con pocos errores.
<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 16"><b>Aprobado</b>
Felicitaciones, a aprobado. Ha pasado la prueba aunque con algunos errores. Siga así y su calificación sera mejor.
<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 15"><b>Aprobado</b>
Felicitaciones, a aprobado. Ha pasado la prueba aunque con algunos errores. Siga así y su calificación sera mejor.
<br><br>
</div>



<div ng-show="count == 14"><b>Aprobado</b>
Felicitaciones, a aprobado. Ha pasado la prueba aunque con algunos errores. Siga así y su calificación sera mejor.
<br><br>
</div>



<div ng-show="count == 13"><b>Aprobado</b>
Felicitaciones, a aprobado. Ha pasado la prueba aunque con algunos errores. Siga así y su calificación sera mejor.
<br><br>
</div>



<div ng-show="count == 12"><b>Aprobado</b>
Felicitaciones, a aprobado. Ha pasado la prueba aunque con algunos errores. Siga así y su calificación sera mejor.
<br><br>
</div>



<div ng-show="count == 11"><b>Aprobado</b>
Felicitaciones, a aprobado. Ha pasado la prueba aunque con algunos errores. Siga así y su calificación sera mejor.
<br><br>
</div>



<div ng-show="count == 10"><b>Aprobado</b>
Felicitaciones, a aprobado. Ha pasado la prueba aunque con algunos errores. Siga así y su calificación sera mejor.
<br><br>
</div>




<div ng-show="count == 9"><b>Reprobado</b>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. Ha tenido varios errores. Intentelo de nuevo.<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 8"><b>Reprobado</b>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. Ha tenido varios errores. Intentelo de nuevo.<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 7"><b>Reprobado</b>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. Ha tenido varios errores. Intentelo de nuevo.<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 6"><b>Reprobado</b>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. Ha tenido varios errores. Intentelo de nuevo.<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 5"><b>Reprobado</b>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. Ha tenido varios errores. Intentelo de nuevo.<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 4"><b>Reprobado</b>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. Ha tenido varios errores. Intentelo de nuevo.<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 3"><b>Reprobado</b>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. Ha tenido varios errores. Intentelo de nuevo.<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 2"><b>Reprobado</b>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. Ha tenido varios errores. Intentelo de nuevo.<br><br>
</div>

<div ng-show="count == 1"><b>Reprobado<br>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. Ha tenido varios errores. Intentelo de nuevo.
<br><br>
</div></b>

<div ng-show="count == 0"><b>Reprobado<br>
Usted no ha pasado la prueba. No ha respondido bien niguna pregunta. Intentelo de nuevo.
<br><br>
</b>

</div>

<div id="chart_div">
</div>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Cerrar" onclick="window.close()"><br>
</center>



</body>
</html>
```

La verdad es que no sé mucho sobre .json, por eso pregunto si es posible que los inputs guarden dichas variables o que se vayan guardando no solo con inputs sino con variables en sí establecidas en la página. Y la información que he leido en internet sobre los .json son cuando ya estan preestablecidos. Agradecería mucho sus respuestas

Comment: Hola, no está muy clara tu pregunta, ¿a qué te refieres con *quiero que el .json este vacio y que se vaya llenando con los inputs de la página* o con *es posible que los inputs guarden dichas variables o que se vayan guardando no solo con inputs sino con variables en sí establecidas en la página*?

Comment: Me refiero a que, en vez de que la variable que contiene el archivo sea por ejemplo: **"nombre":"x",** sea entonces **"nombre":""**, y que al utilizar un input, entonces, si el input tiene asignado z, entonces sea -**"nombre":"z"**, no sé si me explico

Comment: Ahora te he entendido, pero no está muy clara tu pregunta, voy a elaborar una respuesta para ti.

Answer (score 1):

Precisamente el objetivo de usar un framework [MVC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo%E2%80%93vista%E2%80%93controlador) como `Angular` es ese: que cada vez que cambie la vista, cambie el modelo y viceversa. El modelo en tu caso es un objeto, no importa si este objeto lo has creado directamente en el código o lo has leído del servidor en formato `JSON`, `JSON` no es más que un formato ligero de texto con una notación literal de objetos `JavaScript`, al final este fichero cuando es leído mediante el servicio `$http`, en tu código será un objeto. Por ejemplo, observa el siguiente código con un objeto creado directamente en el `$scope`:

```
$scope.datos = {
    nombre : ""
};
```

Esto tendría el mismo resultado que esto:

**Código JSON:**

```
{
    "nombre" : ""
}
```

**Código JavaScript en el controlador**

```
$scope.datos = {};

$http.get("datos.json").then(function (response) {
    $scope.datos = response.data;
});
```

La única diferencia entre los dos, es que el primer código no es asíncrono y el segundo sí (necesita leer los datos del objeto del servidor).

Por lo tanto si tu vista está preparada para que utilice como modelo a ese objeto, cada vez que varíes un dato en la vista el modelo quedará actualizado.

Aquí te dejo el siguiente `snippet`. Por defecto el objeto `datos` contiene tres variables vacías, he situado un método para que cada vez que hagas un cambio en los `inputs` o el `select` lance un `console.log` con una representación `JSON` del objeto usado como modelo. Observa cómo se van llenado los datos en él:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.datos = {

    nombre : "",
    edad   : "",
    sexo   : ""

  };

  $scope.traceResults = function() {

    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.datos));

  };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input name="nombre" ng-model="datos.nombre" ng-change="traceResults()">
    <input name="edad" ng-model="datos.edad" ng-change="traceResults()">
    <select name="sexo" ng-model="datos.sexo" ng-change="traceResults()">
        <option value="">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="m">Masculino</option>
        <option value="f">Femenino</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero como hago después para mostrar las variables ya con un valor especifico?

Comment: @GreciaVPValero, ¿a qué te refieres con *mostrar las variables ya con un valor específico*?

Comment: Por ejemplo, si yo coloco {{datos.nombre}} me va a salir dicha variable, pero como lo colocaria usando un .json?

Comment: @GreciaVPValero, como te he comentado anteriormente, un `JSON` no es más que un formato de texto con una notación literal de objetos `JavaScript`, cuando lees este `JSON` en tu aplicación puedes guardar esa notación en un objeto. Así que para utilizar la variable `nombre` que está dentro de la representación de un objeto que se encuentra en un `JSON`, lo primero que tienes que hacer es leer el `JSON` e igualar la variable `datos` a los datos que te llegan del servidor y después representarla en tu vista como `{{datos.nombre}}` (te lo he situado como ejemplo al inicio de mi explicación).